# Setting dynamic session variables(arrays) with a prefix and looping with foreach

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, joomla3.0

I'm trying to achieve the following task in php:

1. Setting dynamic arrays in session variables.
2. Adding a prefix named order_ to these session variables.
3. Looping through the session variables that starts with the prefix order_.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
foreach($array as $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $subset) {
        $nomInput = $subset['Nom'];
        $inputArray=[
            1=>[
                ['Nom'=>$input->get($nomInput, null, 'string'),
                 'LabelFr'=>$subset['LabelFr'],
                 'LabelEn'=>$subset['LabelEn']]
            ]
         ];

         $session->set('order_'.$nomInput, $inputArray);
     }
}
```

With this code, I'm able to set the variables correctly with the prefix.
However, I can't find a way to loop through the results with a foreach loop.

Can somebody give me some pointers on how to manipulate only the session variables that have the prefix order_ with a foreach loop?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: So this is the code that SETS the data into the session right?

Comment: `array_filter($_SESSION, function($k){ return 0 === strpos($k, 'ThePrefix'); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)` gives you raw `$_SESSION` data. You could then use the JSession to get sanitized values on the found keys. On a session raw should be no problem since the values were stored server side. Not sure if JSession has an own $_SESSION independent implementation.

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone Thanks for your help, could be give me an example of the use of your function with a foreach loop to get into the arrays?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That's right, this code sets the data, thanks!

Comment: I've implemented a more professional and reusable gereric  approach, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Joomla JSession documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Session.Session.html#method_getIterator) the `JSession` class does provide a `getIterator` method returning an `ArrayIterator`.

As a reusable approach, you could implement your own `FilterIterator` class, only iterating over items having a specific prefix and *optionally* stripping the prefix from keys.

In your code you get the iterator by

```
$sessionArrayIter = $session->getIterator();
```

*Since I do not well know Joomla and do not have any installation running, I will spoof that part:*

```
$sessionArray     = ['aa_test1' => 1, 'bb_test2' => 2, 'aa_test3' => 3, 'cc_test4' => 4];
$sessionArrayIter = new ArrayIterator($sessionArray);
```

**Class Implementation**

Then we implement the `PrefixFilterIterator` class extending PHP's abstract `FilterIterator` class.

```
class PrefixFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
  private
    $_prefix,
    $_prefixLength,
    $_strip_prefix
  ;

  public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, string $prefix, bool $strip_prefix = false)
  {
    parent::__construct($iterator);
    $this->set_prefix($prefix, $strip_prefix);
  }

  public function set_prefix(string $prefix, ?bool $strip_prefix = null) : void
  {
    $this->_prefix       = $prefix;
    $this->_prefixLength = strlen($prefix);
    if(null !== $strip_prefix)
      $this->_strip_prefix = $strip_prefix;
  }

  // conditionally remove prefix from key
  public function key()  /* : mixed scalar */
  {
    return $this->_strip_prefix ? substr(parent::key(), $this->_prefixLength) : parent::key();
  }

  // accept prefixed items only
  public function accept() : bool
  {
    return 0 === strpos(parent::key(), $this->_prefix);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

To iterate over the filtered items, we create a new instance of our iterator.

```
$prefixIter = new PrefixFilterIterator($sessionArrayIter, 'aa_', true);

foreach ($prefixIter as $k => $v)
  echo "$k => $v", PHP_EOL;
```

**Output**

```
test1 => 1
test3 => 3
```

[live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79e62babf0a21e37b6d7812b167296ae69838fcf)

***Remarks, Limits, ToDo:***

*The code above runs on **PHP >= 7.1***

*To support PHP 7.0, type hints must be adapted. `:void` is not supported in PHP<7.1 and must be removed, likewise `?bool` must be changed into `bool`.*

*This is a simple implementation focussing the problem in the question to reduce the 'noise' in the answer. `mbstring` is a non-default extension to PHP. Therefore I did not use multibyte string functions. However, array keys may include multibyte charactersets. To support such keys, a conditional implementation of some string function wrappers would be required, using appropriate functions if they are installed. The `preg_*` functions with the `u` modifier could be an alternative to support multibyte unicode keys.*

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, Amen!